¿Por qué las colisiones de este juego utilizando p5library no se ajustan al sprite?
Estoy empezando a usar esta libreria y no tengo muy claro como funcionan las cosas, la base la he sacado de un video de youtube y luego he intentado ir añadiendo cosas.
El problema está en el sprite de la rana se hunde en las plataformas, por lo que supongo que el problema está en que o la imagen de la rana es demasiado grande para el sprite o que este esté mal. Tambien puede ser que las colisiones con las plataformas estén mal o más abajo de lo normal y por eso parece que la rana se hunde en vez de quedarse arriba de la plataforma.
La parte del codigo donde sospecho que puede estar el problema es esta:
 player = new Sprite(width / 2, height - 100, 40, 40, 'd');
 player.rotationLock = true;
 player.image = rana;
 player.scale = 0.05;

/ Pisos
 for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   let f = new floors.Sprite();
   f.w = random(20, 100);
   f.h = 20;
   f.collider = 's';
   f.x = random(leftWall.x + leftWall.w / 2, rightWall.x - rightWall.w / 2); // Generar pisos entre las paredes
   f.y = player.y - (i * 50);
 }

Esto es lo que crea las dimensiones para el sprite de la rana y las dimensiones y la generación de las plataformas en las que hay que saltar. De todas formas aqui está el código javascript completo por si es necesario:
let groundFloor;
let player;
let floors;
let score = 0;
let score_max = 0; 
let music;
let rana;
let sea; 
let seaLevel = 0; 
let gameOver = false; 
let restartButton; 
let seaSpeed = 0.5; 
let seaAccelerationInterval; 

// Precargar la imagen y el sonido
function preload() {
  rana = loadImage('../img/rana_salta.png');
  music = loadSound('../sonido/SonidoJuego.mp3');
}

function setup() {
  // Tamaño pantalla
  let canvas = createCanvas(400, 600);
  // Asegurar que el canvas está en el centro
  canvas.parent('gameContainer'); 
  // Gravedad
  world.gravity.y = 10;

  // Piso del suelo (a una altura y estático)
  groundFloor = new Sprite(0, height - 20, width * 2, 20, 's');

  // Pared izquierda en el extremo del groundFloor
  leftWall = new Sprite(-groundFloor.w / 2 + 10, height / 2, 20, height * 100, 's');
  // Pared derecha en el extremo del groundFloor
  rightWall = new Sprite(groundFloor.w / 2 - 10, height / 2, 20, height * 100, 's');

  // Jugador
  player = new Sprite(width / 2, height - 100, 40, 40, 'd');
  player.rotationLock = true;
  player.image = rana;
  player.scale = 0.05;

  // Mar
  // Iniciar el mar más abajo
  sea = new Sprite(0, height + 300, width * 2, 200, 's'); 
  sea.color = 'blue'; 

  floors = new Group();

  // Pisos
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let f = new floors.Sprite();
    f.w = random(20, 100);
    f.h = 20;
    f.collider = 's';
    f.x = random(leftWall.x + leftWall.w / 2, rightWall.x - rightWall.w / 2); // Generar pisos entre las paredes
    f.y = player.y - (i * 50);
  }
  
  music.loop();

  // Configurar intervalo para acelerar el mar
  startSeaAcceleration();
}

function draw() {
  clear();
  background(0);

  if (!gameOver) {
    // Actualizar la posición del mar
    sea.y -= seaSpeed; 

    // Actualizar el nivel del mar
    seaLevel = floor((height + 300 - sea.y) * 0.5);

    // Verificar colisión con el mar
    if (player.colliding(sea)) {
      endGame(); 
    }

    // Score
    // Para que no sea menor a 0
    if (player.y > 0) {
      score = 0;
    } else {
      // Redondea la posición y del jugador hacia abajo
      score = floor((player.y * -1));
    }

    // Actualizar score_max
    if (score > score_max) {
      score_max = score;
    }

    camera.off();

    //Textos
    textSize(20); 
    fill(255);
    text(`Score: ${score}`, 10, 30); 
    text(`Max Score: ${score_max}`, 10, 60); 
    text(`Sea Level: ${seaLevel}`, 10, 90); 
    camera.on();

    // Fijar la cámara en el jugador
    camera.x = player.x;
    camera.y = player.y;
    camera.zoom = 2;

    // Controles
    // Moverse
    if (kb.pressing('a')) {
      player.x -= 2; 
    } else if (kb.pressing('d')) {
      player.x += 2; 
    }
    // Saltar solo si estás tocando superficies
    if (kb.presses('space') && (player.colliding(floors) || player.colliding(groundFloor))) {
      player.vel.y = -10; 
    }

    spawnFloors();
  } else {
    showGameOverScreen();
  }
}

// Función para configurar el intervalo de aceleración del mar
function startSeaAcceleration() {
  seaAccelerationInterval = setInterval(() => {
    seaSpeed *= 1.05; // Aumentar la velocidad del mar en un 5%
  }, 10000); // Cada 10 segundos
}

// Función para terminar el juego y mostrar la pantalla de "Has perdido"
function endGame() {
  gameOver = true;
  noLoop(); // Detener el bucle de dibujo de p5.js
  clearInterval(seaAccelerationInterval); // Detener la aceleración del mar

  // Crear botón de reiniciar
  restartButton = createButton('Reiniciar');
  restartButton.position((windowWidth / 2) - 50, (windowHeight / 2));
  restartButton.mousePressed(resetGame);
}

// Función para reiniciar el juego
function resetGame() {
  gameOver = false;
  player.x = width / 2;
  player.y = height - 100;
  score = 0;
  sea.y = height + 300; 
  seaSpeed = 0.5; 
  floors.removeAll();

  // Recrear los pisos iniciales
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let f = new floors.Sprite();
    f.w = random(20, 100);
    f.h = 20;
    f.collider = 's';
    // Generar pisos entre las paredes
    f.x = random(leftWall.x + leftWall.w / 2, rightWall.x - rightWall.w / 2); 
    f.y = player.y - (i * 50);
  }

  // Eliminar botón de reiniciar
  restartButton.remove();
  loop(); // Reiniciar el bucle de dibujo

  // Reiniciar la aceleración del mar
  startSeaAcceleration();
}

// Función para mostrar la pantalla de "Has perdido"
function showGameOverScreen() {
  camera.off();
  textSize(50);
  fill(255);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text('Has perdido', width / 2, height / 2 - 100);
  camera.on();
}

function spawnFloors() {
  if (player.y < floors[floors.length - 1].y) {
    let f = new floors.Sprite();
    f.w = random(20, 100);
    f.h = 20;
    f.collider = 's';
    f.x = random(leftWall.x + leftWall.w / 2, rightWall.x - rightWall.w / 2); // Generar pisos entre las paredes
    f.y = player.y - random(50, 100);
  }
}

Muchas gracias.
